# Is it possible to apply styles to undisplayed component?

Tags: material-ui

I am constructing a website using MUI. I am trying to generate a PDF using [jsPDF](https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF) on the client side, but the styles of components that are not displayed on the page are not being applied.

For example, in the code below, I want to generate a PDF for a page where displayDetail is true (which means the Details component is also displayed). However, if I execute the PDF without ever setting displayDetail to true (its initial value being false), the Details components are generated without the applied styles.

Is there a solution to resolve this issue?

```
const App = () => {
  const [displayDetail, setDisplayDetail] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Box>
      <Button onClick={() => setDisplayDetail(!displayDetail)}>
        <Box>
          <Contents />
          {displayDetail && <Details />}
        </Box>
      </Button>
    </Box>
  )
}
```